# Why does use-after-free happen when a linked list node deletes its neighbors in the destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I am having a problem with delete and destructor (I am sure I am making a stupid mistake here, but haven't been able to figure it out as of yet).

When I step through into the destructor, and attempt to call delete on a pointer, the message shows up "Cannot access memory at address *some address*."

The relevant code is:

```
/*
 * Removes the front item of the linked list and returns the value stored
 * in that node.
 *
 * TODO - Throws an exception if the list is empty
 */
std::string LinkedList::RemoveFront()
{
    LinkedListNode *n = pHead->GetNext(); // the node we are removing
    std::string rtnData = n->GetData(); // the data to return

    // un-hook the node from the linked list
    pHead->SetNext(n->GetNext());
    n->GetNext()->SetPrev(pHead);

    // delete the node
    delete n;
    n=0;

    size--;
    return rtnData;
}
```

and

```
/*
 * Destructor for a linked node.
 *
 * Deletes all the dynamically allocated memory, and sets those pointers to 0.
 */
LinkedListNode::~LinkedListNode()
{
    delete pNext; // This is where the error pops up
    delete pPrev;
    pNext=0;
    pPrev=0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are deleting the next and previous nodes of the list from the destructor. Which, if `pNext` and `pPrev` are `LinkedListNode*`, means that you are recursively deleting the whole list :-(

Try this:

```
std::string LinkedList::RemoveFront()
{
    LinkedListNode *n = pHead->GetNext(); // the node we are removing
    std::string rtnData = n->GetData(); // the data to return

    // un-hook the node from the linked list
    pHead->SetNext(n->GetNext());
    n->GetNext()->SetPrev(pHead);

    n->SetNext(0);
    n->SetPrev(0);
    // delete the node
    delete n;
    n=0;

    size--;
    return rtnData;
}

LinkedListNode::~LinkedListNode()
{
}
```

(Actually you don't even need to reset the prev and next pointers to 0 since you are going to delete the node anyway. I left those statements in because they at least put the node into a consistent state, which is a good idea in general. It may make a difference if you later e.g. change your memory management strategy and decide to store unused nodes for later reuse.)

Comment: The next and previous nodes stored in the current node (each node contains some string data, and a pointer to the next and previous nodes in the list). That is the desired behavior, as we have un-hooked this node from the linked list, and now want to return all the dynamically allocated memory EDIT - wait, i think see what you are saying..

Comment: @kyeana: you only want to return the memory associated to the single Node that you're removing

Comment: It's worse than that -- this actually will delete forwards until the end of the list (recursing on the first delete) and then try to delete the second-to-last node again from inside the last node's destructor, which is likely where the crash is.  If X, Y and Z are the last three nodes, ~X is deleting Y, ~Y is deleting Z, and ~Z is deleting Y again.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I knew i was doing something stupid :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's even worse. Z tries to delete whatever its "Next" points to, which is probably either NULL or a random location in memory.

Comment: @Beta AFAIR deleting a null pointer is OK, it does not have any effect. Deleting a dangling pointer is of course very not OK. But I would assume the linked list is terminated correctly with a null pointer - the OP wouldn't have got even this far if he had forgotten about that :-)

Comment: I love the sad face after you mention he is recursively deleting the whole list

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `LinkedListNode` is deleting its neighbours, so when you delete one node it then proceeds to destroy the entire list - note you don't set `pNext` and `pPrev` to NULL when you remove your node.

Also your `LinkedListNode` destructor is problematic even in the case when you want the whole list to be destroyed: having both `delete pNext` and `delete pPrev` will lead to multiple calls of the same destructor (and I think eventually a stack overflow).

Comment: oh god... node 2 deletes nodes 1 and 3, which both try to delete node 2, which deletes nodes 1 and 3 twice each, and then node 2 is deleted again four times, ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't be messing with neighbours in a node. That's for list class to do - connect them properly. In the destructor you can set them to null, but unless you have allocated dynamically something else - you don't have to call `delete`